# Flask knows class in main app but not in html template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have an Flask app which uses a self defined class fruit:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, redirect, url_for, jsonify, send_from_directory, request, make_response, Response
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from Fruit import Fruit
import time
import os
import sys
from io import StringIO
from z3 import *
import jsonpickle
import traceback 
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads'


sysn=sys.version_info.major

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


@app.route("/")
def flask():
    return render_template('index.html', reload=time.time())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Hurra simple working {str(Fruit)}")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

It prints the Fruit representation in main as expected, but trying to bring it up in index.html
Like this:

```
<h1>{{str(Fruit)}}</h1>
```

yields an NameError Fruit not defined. It even tells me that the standard Python-function str isn't defined. What can I do to correct this problem?

Comment: I think you need to pass `Fruit` in `render_template('index.html', reload=time.time(), Fruit=Fruit)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the value of the variable in the HTML file, you have to pass it like this.

```
@app.route("/")
def flask():
    return render_template('index.html', reload=time.time(), Fruit = Fruit)
```